# What was the chronology & dates of the various eras of human history?

Tags: remembrance-of-earths-past

What is the chronology & dates of the various eras of human history from the start of the first Trisolaran contact?

e.g., "crisis era", etc.

As far as I am aware these gradually emerge throughout the trilogy and although I can recall some of the order, the exact time periods & details are hard to remember in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Death's End*, after "A Brief Note from the Translator," is a section titled "Table of Eras," presumably from Cixin Liu with brief descriptions.

Combining @UuDdLrLrSs list, the "Table of Eras" list, Wikipedia information, information in *Death's End* missing from Wikipedia, and the series book titles gives this:

*Remembrance Universe* Timeline:

- *The Three Body Problem*:

  - Common Era (Present–201X) Before humans learned of the existence of Trisolaran civilization.
- *Dark Forest*:

  - Crisis Era (201X–2208) Time period after Trisolaris and the Trisolarans become widely known and sophons begin to block all scientific progress.
  - Deterrence Era (2208–2270) the age after Luo Ji deters the Trisolarans with the threat of mutually assured destruction.
- *Death's End*:

  - Post-Deterrence Era (2270–2272) The age when Trisolarans prepare Earth for Trisolaran settlement.
  - Broadcast Era (2272–2332) Begins after humanity broadcasts the location of Trisolaris from the Oort cloud and one of the three suns of Trisolaris is destroyed. Earth is likewise endangered.
  - Bunker Era - 2333–2400 - most humans living on Earth move to space cities in the shadow of Jupiter and other gas giants, having chosen to use them as shields.
  - Galaxy Era (2273–unknown) focuses on the few survivors of the dark forest strike, and civilization founded by the surviving crews of Blue Space and Gravity and their descendants, referred to as "Galactic Humans."
  - Black Domain Era for DX3906 System (2687–18906416) the DX3906 solar system is transformed into a reduced-lightspeed black domain which permanently isolates the DX3906 solar system and imprisons all who remain inside.

*Universe 647* Timeline:

- also in *Death's End*:

  - (18906416-...) Opens with two humans and the Sophon robot waiting in a time-slowed (relative to the Remembrance Universe) pocket universe until the *Remembrance Universe* ends.

Note that all year numbers are directly quoted from the "Table of Eras"

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death%27s_End#Eras) has the following information (summarized) but it does not have a close accounting of exact time periods / dates, so only partly answers the question.

The following eras were identified in the story:

> - **Common Era**: The period before humans learned of the existence of    Trisolaran civilization.
> - The **Crisis Era** (present era – 2208 AD) is the time period after    Trisolaris and the Trisolarans become widely known and
>     sophons begin    to block all scientific progress.
> - The **Deterrence Era** describes the age after Luo Ji deters the    Trisolarans with the threat of mutually assured destruction.
> - The **Post-Deterrence Era** describes the age when Trisolarans prepare    Earth for Trisolaran settlement.
> - The **Broadcast Era** begins after humanity broadcasts the location of    Trisolaris from the Oort cloud and one of the three
>     suns of    Trisolaris is destroyed. Earth is likewise endangered.
> - In the **Bunker Era**, most humans living on Earth move to space cities    in the shadow of Jupiter and other gas giants, having chosen
>     to use    them as shields.
> - The **Galaxy Era** focuses on the few survivors of the dark forest    strike, and civilization founded by the surviving crews of Blue Space 
>     and Gravity and their descendants, referred to as "Galactic Humans".